# Android, count of rows

Tags: android

is it possible to do smth like this [dynam. rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xuin.png) in Android(TableLayout/LinearLayout etc.). The count of rows in the 3rd column can be  dynamically changed.
Thx!

Comment: You could certainly create this with a `TableLayout`. Please try it yourself and then ask specific questions if/when you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

For LinearLayout,
assuming the layout is vertical, and every child is a row,

you will have to do something similar to:

```
for(int viewCount=0 ; viewCount<mLinearLayout.getChildCount() ; viewCount++) {
    if(viewCount%2==0)
        mLinearLayout.getChildAt(viewCount).setBackground(new ColorDrawable(YOUR_COLOR));
```